# using xautomation in shell file

Tags: shell, ubuntu, automation

I am trying to input something on terminal after reading from file. I am using xautomation for this, but I am not sure how to enter a variable in xautomation. PFB my code -

```
FILENAME="sample.txt"

#set -vx
QUOTES=\'
cat $FILENAME | while read LINE
do
    set -vx

#   echo $QUOTES$STR$LINE$QUOTES
    xte 'sleep 1' \'$LINE\' 'key Return'
    #read the output and put in the output text file
done
```

**EDIT:** but on terminal it gives output as -

```
+ read LINE
+ set -vx
+ xte 'sleep 1' ''\''str' 'pwd'\''' 'key Return'

Unknown command ''str'
Unknown command 'pwd''
```

**EDIT2**
1 command - `xte 'sleep 1' 'str pwd' 'key Return'` This will give output of pwd command. so while running any code I need to put quotes around it.

Please let me know if I am doing it wrongly, I am new to shell programming.

thanks

Comment: `set -vx` before your `while` loop will show you each line as it is being executed with variable values in place. See what is being executed should give you a big clue about what is the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Shellter, I used this but I am not sure how to place single quotes around the var LINE to output in xte command.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xautomation. The single-quoting doesn't quite make sense. Can you get 1 command to work directly from the command line, and add it to your question? Are you sure you need quoting if there are no spaces in the arguments? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
xte 'sleep 1' "${LINE}" 'key Return'
```

You have to use double quotes to preserve the variable and use the proper format for calling variables in strings.

Quoting the [GNU Bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. When the shell is in POSIX mode (see Bash POSIX Mode), the ‘!’ has no special meaning within double quotes, even when history expansion is enabled. The characters ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see Shell Expansions). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, history expansion will be performed unless an ‘!’ appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the ‘!’ is not removed.